# Download Google Docs From Links

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

I have a list of 500 Google Docs links on a spreadsheet. Would like to download all the Google Docs in a one go WITHOUT opening the Google links?

Please help me on this as soon as possible.

Comment: Can I ask you about `download` you are thinking? Because Google Docs cannot be directly downloaded. Those are required to be exported as Microsoft Docs, PDF, text and so on. What direction do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the links in an excel spreadsheet and use formulas to change the links like so:

Google doc web viewer link:

```
https://www.drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```

to

```
https://www.drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("https://www.drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=",MID(<original_link>,33,SEARCH("/",RIGHT(<original_link>,LEN(<original_link>)-33))))
```

now you have links that you can click and it will directly download.
With the help of a simple batch file you can open and download all files:
    code required to launch each link:

```
start chrome <link>
```

change formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("start chrome https://www.drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=",MID(<original_link>,33,SEARCH("/",RIGHT(<original_link>,LEN(<original_link>)-33))))
```

Make a .txt file:
(paste links)

```
@echo off
start chrome <link>
start chrome <link>
start chrome <link>
.
.
.
```

change extension to .bat

double-click bat file to run